# Как происходит выделения в управляемую кучу?

Tags: c#, память, ram

Вовремя изучения работы памяти в .NET я столкнулся с тем, что не смог найти наглядного примера выделения оперативной памяти в управляемую кучу. Из-за этого у меня появилась теория:
Сначала происходит резервирование памяти, например, `int` или `MyClass` потом даётся названия зарезервированному участку памяти, например, `int i` или `MyClass myclass` и далее уже следует само выделение памяти в зарезервированный участок памяти и проброса указателя на него в стек с помощью оператора `new`, например, `int i = 5;` или `Myclass maclass = new MyClass();`
Верна ли моя теория или как всё-таки это работает?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/botr/garbage-collection.md

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpUkQYy-K8Y-wYcDgDXKhfs6OT8fFQtVm